# The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, ground-control

I tried to warp a raster image, a old airplane image, for projection by using gdalwarp.

My code:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=utm +zone=52 +datum=WGS84' 1954_airplane_photo.tif air_warp.tif
```

But, I had this error:

```
ERROR 1: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for 1954_airplane_photo.tif. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.
```

So, I found [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-SRC-METHOD-NO-GEOTRANSFORM-td5439811.html), and then I revised my code:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=utm +zone=52 +datum=WGS84' -to SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM 1954_airplane_photo.tif air_warp.tif
```

With this action, I could make a raster image with projection without any error. But, the image was flipped! A left picture(1954_airplane_photo.tif) is the image before warping, and a right picture(air_warp.tif) is the image after warping.

[image]!

I leave their gdalinfo

**1954_airplain_photo.tif

```
Files: 1954_airplane_photo.tif
Size is 11358, 22200
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,22200.0)
Upper Right (11358.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (11358.0,22200.0)
Center      ( 5679.0,11100.0)
Band 1 Block=11358x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=11358x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=11358x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=11358x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
    Computed Min/Max=255.000,255.000
```

**air_warp.tif

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: air_warp.tif
Size is 11358, 22200
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 52N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Transverse Mercator",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",129,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",32652]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (0.000000000000000,22200.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (       0.000,   22200.000) (124d30'40.42"E,  0d12' 0.83"N)
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (124d30'40.52"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Upper Right (   11358.000,   22200.000) (124d36'46.77"E,  0d12' 0.93"N)
Lower Right (   11358.000,       0.000) (124d36'46.87"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Center      (    5679.000,   11100.000) (124d33'43.67"E,  0d 6' 0.44"N)
Band 1 Block=11358x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=11358x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=11358x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=11358x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
    Computed Min/Max=255.000,255.000
```

I met this issue before. Back then, it worked in the satellite image [image]!
I also share the information that gdalwarp worked
The code:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=utm +zone=48 +datum=WGS84' [Input_file] [Output_file]
```

Before warping, gdalinfo about one band(blue band) of raster image(left) from QGIS.

```
(base) [changwan@localhost IMAGE]$ gdalinfo K3A_20200418061617_27962_00034975_L1R_B.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: K3A_20200418061617_27962_00034975_L1R_B.tif
Size is 6015, 4000
GCP Projection = 
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (0,0) -> (103.160584356099,48.0997742216836,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (6015,0) -> (103.396471325297,48.1804790391136,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (6015,4000) -> (103.431288901204,48.0639064478679,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (0,4000) -> (103.195918277792,47.983229856157,0)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2020:05:08 10:37:32
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=KOMPSAT-3A AEISS-A Product
  TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=16383
  TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=0
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4000.0)
Upper Right ( 6015.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 6015.0, 4000.0)
Center      ( 3007.5, 2000.0)
Band 1 Block=6015x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

After warping, gdalinfo about the rgb raster image(right) from QGIS.

```
(base) [changwan@localhost Downloads]$ gdalinfo test_scaled4.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test_scaled4.tif
Size is 7120, 7130
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 48N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Transverse Mercator",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",105,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",32648]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (338949.338254110654816,5352124.143967485055327)
Pixel Size = (2.200000000000000,-2.200000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  338949.338, 5352124.144) (102d49'41.73"E, 48d18' 6.47"N)
Lower Left  (  338949.338, 5336438.144) (102d50' 3.19"E, 48d 9'38.79"N)
Upper Right (  354613.338, 5352124.144) (103d 2'21.66"E, 48d18'20.13"N)
Lower Right (  354613.338, 5336438.144) (103d 2'41.04"E, 48d 9'52.38"N)
Center      (  346781.338, 5344281.144) (102d56'11.90"E, 48d13'59.62"N)
```

But, why? Now? what's the problem in my code? In fact, I had a hard time to understand the error. Help me out please.

Comment: You can't really warp an image into a new coordinate system if you do not know what is the original coordinate system. Having corner coordinates `Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0) ( Lower Right (11358.0,22200.0)` without ground control points means just that, a 11358 by 22200 pixel sized image at an unknown place.  In the latter example the image contains ground control points which tie the pixel coordinates into coordinates in the spatial reference system. Thus the source is known and conversion into target succeeds.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for your clear comment. But, when I downloaded the old airplane photo from the national official site, I chose the place by myself. This means I know coordinate system, UTM ZONE=52, such that I used in the gdalwarp. In the base of your comment,  although I know the UTM zone of the old plane photo, I cannot warp an image If I do not know the Ground Control Points. Is it right? So, How can I get the Ground Control Points?

Comment: Do you know for example the upper left - lower right coordinates is some coordinate system? One alternative is to use the QGIS georeferencer https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html.

Comment: Ok, I got that. I really appreciate you comments.