# How to give a coordinate to *.tif?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, coordinates, georeferencing, gdalinfo, ground-control

I have a *.tif, vintage aerial photo. Also, there is a metadata with coordinate information corresponding to the aerial photo. **I would like to give that coordinate to the *.tif.***

First of all,
When I use gdalinfo for that *.tif, I got this information below.

```
gdalinfo 197709000100090035.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 197709000100090035.tif
Size is 11284, 12146
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,12146.0)
Upper Right (11284.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (11284.0,12146.0)
Center      ( 5642.0, 6073.0)
Band 1 Block=11284x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

In the metadata, I have coordinate information below.

X and Y coordinate of origin : (222926, 380970)

Datum: GRS80

Projection: TM

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=129 +k=1 +x_0=200000 +y_0=600000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

NB: I do not have any GCP for the photo.

Can I give the coordinate information to the *.tif like result from gdalinfo of the georeferenced photo below ?

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Georef_Dasan_1953_High_Ortho.tif
Size is 12481, 23194
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["Korea 2000 / Central Belt 2010",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Korea 2000",
        DATUM["Geocentric datum of Korea",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,    
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],       
        ID["EPSG",4737]],
    CONVERSION["Korea Central Belt 2010",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",38,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],        
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",127,       
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],        
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,      
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",200000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",600000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["northing (X)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["easting (Y)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Cadastre, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Republic of Korea (South Korea) - onshore between 126°E and 128°E."],
        BBOX[33.14,126,38.33,128]],
    ID["EPSG",5186]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (402256.840099999972153,389529.193000000028405)   
Pixel Size = (0.222111673744093,-0.222111671121842)        
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  402256.840,  389529.193) (129d14'43.37"E, 36d 4'56.86"N)
Lower Left  (  402256.840,  384377.535) (129d14'38.63"E, 36d 2' 9.84"N)
Upper Right (  405029.016,  389529.193) (129d16'34.09"E, 36d 4'54.77"N)
Lower Right (  405029.016,  384377.535) (129d16'29.27"E, 36d 2' 7.76"N)
Center      (  403642.928,  386953.364) (129d15'36.34"E, 36d 3'32.31"N)
Band 1 Block=12481x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=12481x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

Two years ago, I also asked a similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398175/the-transformation-is-already-north-up-or-a-transformation-between-pixel-line).
I am still confused.

Comment: You can't give a pixel a coordinate. You have to give at least three, preferably far apart, so that a formula can be derived to scale the pixels to a plane.  And then the image has to be orthorectified.

Comment: @Vince Thank you for your comment. After posting this issue, I also thought that If I know the coordinate of just a point, then the photo could not be fixed on the map. And, What do you mean "so that a formula can be derived to scale the pixels to a plane. "? I know the measurement scale was 1:20000.

Comment: If it's a vintage photo, it's not likely to be perfectly orthagonal to an existing coordinate reference. The only way to georectify the image is to georectify it. This involves scaling and removing skew. In fact, you won't know the actual image scale until you're done.

Comment: @Vince In fact, I used the metashape to get an orthophoto from a couple of vintage aerial photos. And then the vintage orthophoto was georeferenced from current orthoimage with coordinate. It's really painful and time-consuming. So I hoped to use metadata in order to give coordinate to raw vintage aerial photos without georeferencing. The problem is that metadata is poor. How do you think of the suggestion of the answer from the Ian?

Comment: The *output* of registration is a world file, which is then used to georectify. You still have some work to do.

Comment: @Vince Many thanks to you! I learned a lot from this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the pixel size of the images (or the ground size of the image) then you can create a [world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) for the image.

> ```
> Line 1: A: pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel
> Line 2: D: rotation about y-axis
> Line 3: B: rotation about x-axis
> Line 4: E: pixel size in the y-direction in map units, almost always negative
> Line 5: C: x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
> Line 6: F: y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
> ```

Lines 2 & 3 are normally 0 and you know the values for lines 5 & 6

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The metadata says that it is projected in TM projection. In the case of TM, Is your suggestion effective? I do not know the pixel size. But, I know the extra information. This vintage aerial photo was scanned by the Photoscan TD Scanner.  The type of camera was RC-8. The number of lense was 404. The focal length was 152 mm. The type of flim was KODAK-XX. Do the information help me get pixel size?

Comment: The projection makes no difference, if you know the size of the image in ground units then you can calculate the pixel size other wise you will need to manually geolocate features on the image to georeference it

Comment: Ok. I hardly know the size of the image. Now, think about this. There is a structure captured in both a vintage aerial photo and also a current orthophoto. I know the size of the structure from the current ortho photo. With this information, Can we estimate the ground pixel size of the vintage aeral photo?  Of course, I think the accuray of the ground pixel size would be low. Besides, the error propagate to the quality of the vintage photo in the accuracy of the coordinate.